# WPF and graph in the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, grid

I would like to draw a linechart-like graph in a grid column in WPF (C#).

Something like this:

[image]

Obviously to make it look good I need to style the grid to not have cell borders, but that's not a problem. The problem is how would I even approach this? There's no column type that sounds good and since the graph is all connected it feels like painful to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure why you need `Grid` control, actually here. May be `ListView` would enough for you ? It's much more lightweight then `Grid` control.

To draw that stuff you *could*

- make use of [Adorners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29001/Group-Sort-Adorner-ListView) in order to draw something semitransparent **over** the items.

or

- Define a style for the control (`ListView` or `Grid`) where on left side you have `Canvas` element which overlaps the items collection of the control.

or

- can try to use very customizable `TreeControl` like from [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17379/Advanced-Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF) from Josh Smith, but naturally with your changes.

Good luck.

Comment: I think the `Canvas` approach is the best. Can you give me a headstart how do I place a canvas element into one of the grid's column?

Comment: @rFactor: I think you can use [StackPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html) to place controls.